# How to get object specific events using Box Api

Tags: events, box-api

I am having difficulty getting the events for a specific object. Basically I would like to have an event collection that reprents the "Access Stats" when looking at a file's properties on box.com. The only way I can figure to do it now is to run through all events in the stream and manually build the collection. Is there not an endpoint I can use or a query filter I can put on the events endpoint to accomplish this?

Thanks

Shawn

Answer (score 1):

This is something our fields parameter would help with, but it's not yet GET /events. Keep an eye on this portion of our documentation for when support for this is available. http://developers.box.com/docs/#fields